# find nested keys in dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have several dictionaries, dictionary keys are tuples.

Keys are always same length in each dictionary.

I'd like to find nested keys and print them.

dictionaries example :

```
dic_1 = {
    (u'A_String', u'B_String', u'C_String', u'D_String', u'E_String'): 111, 
    (u'A_String', u'B_String', u'C_String', u'D_String' ,u'F_String'): 112
}

 dic_2 = {
     (u'A_String', u'B_String', u'C_String', u'D_String'): 300, 
     (u'A_String', u'B_String', u'C_String', u'F_String'): 301,
 }

dic_3 = {
    (u'A_String', u'B_String', u'C_String'): 200, 
    (u'A_String', u'B_String', u'F_String'): 201,
}
```

First row in `dic_3` is nested in first row in `dic_2` and `dic_1`

First row in `dic_2` is nested in first row of `dic_1`

I tried:

```
for key in dic_1:
    print '-',key
    for k in dic_2:
        if k in tuple(key):
            print '--', k
            for i in dic_3:
                if i in tuple(k):
                    print '---', i
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Read the question to fast, here is an edit that answer it.

```
dic_1 = {
 (u'A_String', u'B_String', u'C_String', u'D_String', u'E_String'): 111,
 (u'A_String', u'B_String', u'C_String', u'D_String' ,u'F_String'): 112
}


dic_2 =  {
 (u'A_String', u'B_String', u'C_String', u'D_String'): 300,
 (u'A_String', u'B_String', u'C_String', u'F_String'): 301,
 }


dic_3 =  {
 (u'A_String', u'B_String', u'C_String'): 200,
 (u'A_String', u'B_String', u'F_String'): 201,
}

from itertools import permutations

dicts = [dic_1, dic_2, dic_3]
for x, y in  permutations(range(len(dicts)), 2):
    print x, y
    dic_x = dicts[x]
    dic_y = dicts[y]
    for k in dic_x.keys():
        for j in dic_y.keys():
            if len(set(k) - set(j)) is 0:
                print 'Key %s of dict %s is contained in key %s of dict %s' % (k, x + 1, j, y + 1)
                break
```

> Key (u'A_String', u'B_String', u'C_String', u'D_String') of dict 2 is contained in key (u'A_String', u'B_String', u'C_String', u'D_String', u'E_String') of dict 1
>   Key (u'A_String', u'B_String', u'C_String', u'F_String') of dict 2 is contained in key (u'A_String', u'B_String', u'C_String', u'D_String', u'F_String') of dict 1
>   Key (u'A_String', u'B_String', u'F_String') of dict 3 is contained in key (u'A_String', u'B_String', u'C_String', u'D_String', u'F_String') of dict 1
>   Key (u'A_String', u'B_String', u'C_String') of dict 3 is contained in key (u'A_String', u'B_String', u'C_String', u'D_String', u'E_String') of dict 1
>   Key (u'A_String', u'B_String', u'F_String') of dict 3 is contained in key (u'A_String', u'B_String', u'C_String', u'F_String') of dict 2
>   Key (u'A_String', u'B_String', u'C_String') of dict 3 is contained in key (u'A_String', u'B_String', u'C_String', u'D_String') of dict 2

It works by comparing everything, the comparison is done by casting to a set and doing the difference, if no elements stays, the tuples is contained in the other.

Comment: Wow ! Can you please comment on `permutations(range(3), 2)` ? If I have eight dictionaries ? Longest key lenght eight and smalles one , do I need to change parameters ?

Comment: If you have 8 dict: permutations(range(8), 2) try adding a print after the for to see what x and y are.

Comment: Can the code work with one dictionary ? to find a parent key (longest length), then keys they are subset of  it ? How I can change the code to accomplish that ?

Comment: Put the dict twice in dicts.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how are your dicts organised, but to find if any of keys from one dictionary is "nested" within key of another dictionary, you can check it like that:

```
dic_3_keys = dic_3.keys()
key_len = len(dic_3_keys[0])
check_keys = [k[:key_len] for k in dic_1.keys()]
for key in dic_3_keys:
    if key in check_keys:
        print key
```

Comment: Thanks ! Is the idea here to get same key lenght for both dictionaries ?

Comment: If you like to compare them, yes.

Comment: so my problem was comparison keys of diffrent length ? Nice !

Comment: I meant, if you like to find if a key makes prefix in any of keys from another dict. The thing is that your question is not very well defined and this is how I understood you definition of "nested". If you define your question better I can adapt my example accordingly. My code snipped is just an example how would I go about finding if one key is included in another in the way I just described, but I am not sure if it is what you wanted.

Comment: I wanted to find keys they are subset of other keys , and then group them together with a parent key . At the beginning I had one dictionary , but I thought to separate the dictionary to several dictionaries is better idea , separate according to length of keys (maybe it was silly )

Comment: Can you use frozen sets as keys? It would simplify your task significantly. Basically, is you use right datatype from the beginning, coding goes like puzzles :-D

Comment: Please kindly explain more . I new to Python .

Comment: OK. You are trying to find which keys of a dictionary are subsets of keys of another dictionary. The best would be to use frozen sets as dictionary keys when you create them, if it is you who creates them. Then you could just do the check, for example using "issubset" method - you can read about sets here https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html . Please make sure to use frozen sets as keys, as ordinary sets being "unhashable" type can not be used as dictionary keys.